# Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop VB project templates missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop and cannot open existing VB projects. They show as "incompatible" (The application is not installed).

In addition, when I attempt to created a New Project, no Visual Basic templates appear in the list of 'Installed' templates. The only language-specific templates that show up are Visual C#. I also see the Blank Solution template.

A full suite of VB template definitions is found on this path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress\ProjectTemplates\VisualBasic\Windows\1033...there are definitions for five project templates in the subfolders.

However, none of them appear in the IDE.

In the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012, I have executed wdexpress.exe /installvstemplates. This appears to run without error, but no difference is noted in the template list, after restarting VS and rebooting the Windows 7 Pro machine.

Edit: I might also add that I have run Visual Studio's repair feature, which did not make any difference.

Comment: Try this: http://geekswithblogs.net/ehammersley/archive/2005/11/08/59451.aspx

Comment: Check if your program is linked to the correct locations for the templates. under Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions ... C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates". Or mybe somthing is wrong with the setup.msi mybe read this https://geonet.esri.com/thread/67931

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for giving it a look. I've been scouring the web all day but did not see this blog post. I suppose it is because it references VS2005. At any rate, his suggestion I have tried already, and I can't seem to access any of the 298 comments to his post. The "link" doesn't work for me, in Firefox or IE. Strange...

Comment: @Creator The label above the project templates textbox says "User", so I had only paid brief attention to it before now - assuming that VS looks elsewhere for the system templates. On a lark, however, I pointed it at the 'system' location and was surprised to see that it works - sort of. It doubles up on the C# templates but still displays none of the VB templates. So, my installation of VS can locate both system and user templates but does not recognize Visual Basic templates. Thank you, also - I read that post earlier today. Went over it again but nothing new presents itself.

Comment: I am now uninstalling the fool thing and shall reinstall it. Will update if I figure out the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reinstalling the product, the Visual Basic templates are visible.

Windows Update then wanted Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (KB2781514). I let it install, and the Visual Basic templates are still visible.

Why, I cannot guess. Sadly, I have grown accustomed to failure when installing and using the versions of Visual Studio, most especially The Grey Ghost (2012).